# Grouping two lists of filenames using string match

Tags: python

I have list of files 'L1' as follows:

```
L1 = ['D://carrot_25kg', 'D://banana_5kg', 'D://apple_50kg']
```

I have another list of files 'L2' as follows:

```
L2 = ['D://box3_5kg', 'D://box1_25kg', 'D://box2_50kg']
```

I needed to group files as follows.

```
result = [['D://carrot_25kg', 'D://box1_25kg'],
          ['D://banana_5kg', 'D://box3_5kg'],
          ['D://apple_50kg', 'D://box1_50kg']] #the order is not important
```

It is to match based on "_xxkg" string.
How can I do it guys?

Comment: Are these supposed to be pairs only? Should the box always be the final member of each list? Suppose I added "cherry_25kg" in L1. Would the result include `['D://carrot_25kg', 'charry_25kg', 'D://box1_25kg']?

Comment: @tdelaney I have these lists in pairs only.

Comment: Pleas do not make material changes to a question (such as adding L3 and L4) after people start answering.

Comment: @MatBailie actually i forgot to ask real problem associated L3 and L4, but already deleted the changes.

Comment: Forgetting and then adding it is still making a material change.

Comment: @MatBailie yes, i agree and thus deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grouping by a suffix, let's use a dictionary:

```py
d = {
    path.split('_')[-1]: [path]
    for path in L1
}

for path in L2:
    suffix = path.split('_')[-1]
    d[suffix] = d.get(suffix, [])
    d[suffix].append(path)

list(d.values())
[['D://carrot_25kg', 'D://box1_25kg'],
 ['D://banana_5kg', 'D://box3_5kg'],
 ['D://apple_50kg', 'D://box2_50kg']]
```

Or, using a defaultdictionary:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain


d = defaultdict(list)

for path in chain(L1, L2):
    suffix = path.split('_')[-1]
    d[suffix].append(path)

list(d.values())
[['D://carrot_25kg', 'D://box1_25kg'],
 ['D://banana_5kg', 'D://box3_5kg'],
 ['D://apple_50kg', 'D://box2_50kg']]
```

Comment: thanks, what else for the case of "L3" and "L4" ?

Comment: That's a new SO question. Play with this solution a bit, I bet you'll get it

Comment: For L3 and L4, you can use the same script, only changing the `suffix = ...` statement; use a regex to extract the weight from the filename ( `r'_({\d}+kg)'` should do nicely).

Comment: @Swifty other than regex way ?, because i'm not good at it